# How to print log in file used by moduleNameMapper configuration?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I create a `styleMock` file to stub out `css` style files used in the JS files.

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': '<rootDir>/styleMock.js',
  }
};
```

`styleMock.js`:

```js
console.log('style mock');

module.exports = new Proxy(
  {},
  {
    get: function getter(target, key) {
      console.log('key: ', key);
      if (key === '__esModule') {
        return false;
      }
      return key;
    },
  }
);
```

`index.js`:

```js
import './index.css';

export function MyComponent() {
  return null;
}
```

`index.css`:

```css
.my-component {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { MyComponent } from './';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(MyComponent()).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

I try to print logs inside the `getter` method. But when I run the `jest` command:

```
 PASS  issues/console-log-in-module-name-mapper-file/index.test.js (9.146 s)
  MyComponent
    ✓ should pass (1 ms)

  console.log
    style mock

      at Object.<anonymous> (styleMock.js:1:9)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.2 s
```

Only the `console.log` used in module scope works. Why does the `console.log` in the getter method not print the log?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Because I didn't try to access the property of CSS style obj. We should use `.css` files as CSS modules.

```js
import s from './index.css';

export function MyComponent() {
  console.log(s.MyComponent);
  return null;
}
```

```
 PASS  issues/console-log-in-module-name-mapper-file/index.test.js (9.639 s)
  MyComponent
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

  console.log
    style mock

      at Object.<anonymous> (styleMock.js:1:9)

  console.log
    key:  __esModule

      at Object.getter [as get] (styleMock.js:7:15)

  console.log
    key:  MyComponent

      at Object.getter [as get] (styleMock.js:7:15)

  console.log
    MyComponent

      at Object.MyComponent (issues/console-log-in-module-name-mapper-file/index.js:4:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.7 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```